# Upgrading from 14.04 to 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

Currently running 14.04 (development branch) but want to go to 14.04 LTS. Will a `do-release-upgrade` do this for me?

`user@host:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

Answer (score 2):

14.04 is in itself no matter what LTS. That was the only one. There is no "regular" Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Guessing I'm confused because this server differs from another one I have that clearly says "Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" with a `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Huh. Well I guess `do-release-upgrade` may work for ya. You do have the development branch, but the only thing is that the release description wouldn't really have to say that. But there should be no difference. Here's what I got when I put in `lsb_release -a`: `No LSB modules are available.`
`Distributor ID: Ubuntu`
`Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`
`Release: 14.04` `Codename: trusty`

Comment: And Besides. There is no difference except one is development branch.